# dynamic page redirection with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have removed all .php extension from all the pages. It is working fine, but after that, if I Check my site with abc.php it is also working.

So how can I redirect page if someone write abc.php to the abc page without .php extension.

Below is my code for remove .php extension in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use these set of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```